# "Do" notation in Elixir and Haskell

Tags: elixir, do-notation

I have been using "do/end" notation in elixir more-or-less like imperative block delimiters.  (In other words, `do` is like `{` in a C-like language, `end` is like `}`).

Is this an accurate description of what's going on?  Or is it more like the Haskell `do` notation, which constructs syntactic sugar for a monad that allows for imperative-like coding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no. `do`/`end` is a syntactic convenience for keyword lists.

You have probably written if expressions before. What someone may expect to see is something like

```
if predicate do
  true_branch
else
  false_branch
end
```

This can also be written using keyword lists. The following is the exact same.

```
if predicate, do: true_branch, else: false_branch
```

Using the `do`/`end` notation allows us to remove verbosity when writing blocks of code. The following two if expressions are equivelent

```
if predicate do
  a = foo()
  bar(a)
end

if predicate, do: (
  a = foo()
  bar(a)
)
```

This is the same for defining functions. the [`def/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#def/2) macro uses a keyword list as well. Meaning you can define a function like the following

```
def foo, do: 5
```

You can read more about this in the [getting started](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#doend-blocks) guide.